# Reinterpreted pointer does not point to correct memory location

Tags: c++, memory, reinterpret-cast

Suppose I got this in Message.h:

```
#ifndef _MESSAGE_H_
#define _MESSAGE_H_
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
enum PRIMITIVE{
      MESSAGE_1 = 100,
      MESSAGE_2,
};

enum { MSG_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 1024 };

class Header{
    protected:
        Header(PRIMITIVE prim, u_int32 transNum) : m_primitive(prim), m_transNum(transNum) { }
    public:
        // access
        PRIMITIVE primitive() const { return m_primitive; }
        u_int32 transNum()  const { return m_transNum; }
        virtual ~Header(){}
    private:
        PRIMITIVE m_primitive;
        u_int32 m_transNum;
    };

class Message
{
public:
    Message() { reset(); }
    // access
    char* addr() { return reinterpret_cast<char*>(m_buffer); }
    const char* addr() const { return reinterpret_cast<const char*>(m_buffer); }
    u_int32 size() { return sizeof(m_buffer); }
    // msgs
    Header* msgHeader() { return reinterpret_cast<Header*>(addr()); }
    const Header* msgHeader() const { return reinterpret_cast<const Header*>(addr()); }
    // modify
    void reset() {
        memset(&m_buffer, 0, MSG_SIZE_IN_BYTES);
    }
private:
    u_int64 m_buffer[MSG_SIZE_IN_BYTES / sizeof(u_int64)];
};
#endif
```

In `main.cpp`, I casted the `m_buffer` in Message into `Header` type. The point is that I can access memory according to `Header` layout:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Message msg;

    char* content = msg.addr();
    int prim = 100;
    int trans_num = 1;

    memcpy(content, &prim, 4);
    memcpy(content+4, &trans_num, 4);       

    const Message::Header* hdr = msg.msgHeader();
    Message::PRIMITIVE hdr_prim = hdr->primitive();
    u_int32 hdr_transNum = hdr->transNum();

    cout << "Memory address of Message: " << &msg << endl;

    cout << "Memory address of Message buffer: " << (void*) msg.addr() << endl;             
    cout << "Memory address of content: " <<  content << endl;      

    cout << "Memory address of Header: " << hdr << endl;
    cout << "Memory address of m_primitive in Header: " <<  &hdr_prim << endl;
    cout << "Memory address of m_transNum in Header: " <<  &hdr_transNum << endl;

    cout << "Primitive in Header: " << prim << endl;        
    cout << "Trans num in Header: " << transNum << endl;
}
```

The `Header* hdr` is supposed to point to the same memory address as `Message msg`, and the `m_primitive` is supposed to be at the same address as `Header* hdr`, and the `m_transNum` is `&m_primitive + 4`.

However, this is the actual value:

```
Memory address of Message: 0x699520

Memory address of Message buffer: 0x699520
Memory address of content: 0x699520

Memory address of Header: 0x699520
Memory address of m_primitive in Header: 0x7f2ec2f2738c
Memory address of m_transNum in Header: 0x7f2ec2f27388

Primitive in Header: 1
Trans num in Header: 1953719668
```

`m_primitive` and `m_transNum` pointed to a completely random location and got garbage values! How can it happen? `reinterpret_cast` is supposed to change the layout according to class type, by casting to differnt type of pointer.

Also, if it returns a copy, the value of `m_primitive` should be 100, and `m_transNum` should be 1, because I `memcpy` into the buffer `char* content` of `msg`. But the values are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Message::PRIMITIVE hdr_prim = hdr->primitive();
u_int32 hdr_transNum = hdr->transNum();

...

cout << "Memory address of m_primitive in Header: " <<  &hdr_prim << endl;
cout << "Memory address of m_transNum in Header: " <<  &hdr_transNum << endl;
```

You are printing addresses of local stack variables to which you assigned values of your `Header` data members. These addresses are not related to addresses of original variables.

Try (see EDIT below with regard to `virtual` destructor)

```
const Message::Header* hdr = msg.msgHeader();
Message::PRIMITIVE * hdr_prim = ( Message::PRIMITIVE * ) hdr;
u_int32 * hdr_transNum = ( u_int32 *) ( ( ( char * ) hdr ) + sizeof( Message::PRIMITIVE ) );

...

cout << "Memory address of m_primitive in Header: " <<  hdr_prim << endl;
cout << "Memory address of m_transNum in Header: " <<  hdr_transNum << endl;
```

That's under assumption there is no padding. But `enum` field size should be `int`, usually. So it's 4 bytes and there is no padding. But check it to be sure.

EDIT: I just saw you have `virtual` destructor in `Header`. The above won't work, since there is a pointer to `vtable` insider `Header` object. Where it is placed is compiler specific. You can try some experimenting and adjust your offsets accordingly.

Comment: I see. However, I don't understand, if it returns a copy, it shouldn't have garbage values. When I printed the values out, the value is incorrect.

Comment: I'm very sorry. The `FCPMsg` should be `Message`, and `MsgHeader` should be `Header`. Please fix it to make it consistent.

Comment: Mark answered that in his comment.

Comment: Thanks for both of you. It is correct, I have to manually align to make it fit. Actually, this is legacy code and I have to refactor it. So, can you please give me a link to explain what else is contained in a data segment of C++ class? I thought it was like C struct.

Comment: @Amumu If there is no virtual things, like functions or inheritance, then objects' layout does follow C struct style. With virtual things added, compiler puts (implementation dependent) additional hidden information into objects. [Inside C++ Object Model](http://www.amazon.ca/Inside-Object-Model-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0201834545) by Stanley Lippman is really good for that kind of stuff. It has whole chapter dedicated to object memory layout under different conditions (simple, inheritance, multiple inheritance, virtual inheritance etc.). It describes a few models and actual implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Your `primitive()` and `transNum()` functions aren't returning a reference to the member variables, they're returning a *copy*. Of course the copy won't have the same address as the original.

Comment: Ah right, but how can I got garbage values in `m_primitive` and `m_transNum` if it returns a copy?

Comment: @Amumu, your Header class has a virtual function in it, which means it will have an invisible vtable pointer in the layout, probably at the front. You're making too many assumptions about the binary layout of objects and running into undefined behavior.